# Kivy / Python: How to convert float color list to web rgb?

Tags: python, web, colors, kivy, converters

How can I convert Kivy's  `[0.5019607843137255, 0.796078431372549, 0.7686274509803922, 1.0]` float color list to web rgb (i.e. `#AABBCCDD`) in Python?

The list consist of RGBA colors in float format where `0..255` is represented as `0..1` and each color is the list element not the byte string.

Comment: There are some [utility](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.utils.html#kivy.utils.get_hex_from_color) functions built-in kivy for that kind of job. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this kind of color representation with simple oneliner:

```
'#%02X%02X%02X%02X' % tuple(int(255*i) for i in c)
```

Example:

```
c = [0.5019607843137255, 0.796078431372549, 0.7686274509803922, 1.0]
rgb = '#%02X%02X%02X%02X' % tuple(int(255*i) for i in c)
'#80CBC4FF'
```